# New menu is not showing in api response

Tags: menus, rest-api

I just make a custom Menu because I wanted to add a link in my menu but for some reason the new menus are not showing in the API response. any idea why and how should I fix this?

I add a new menu called "Menu Item" and "Link Bar" but it's not showing in the wp json response.

https://chinblog.com/

https://chinblog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/

Comment: Menu items aren’t Pages. You’re using the Pages endpoint. That only returns things in Pages > All Pages. Use the menus endpoints: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/24/menus-endpoints-in-wordpress-5-9/

Comment: @JacobPeattie oh ok, by any chance do you know what might be this problem. So I created an app and when I have the default menu bar in my WordPress, it reflects exactly in my app but after I make a custom menu in WordPress, it didn't reflect new changes in my mobile app at all. It's still showing the old menus.

Comment: Did you actually read my comment? Your app is using the Pages endpoint to list pages. This just happens to be the default behaviour of your theme when it doesn’t have a custom menu. If your site is using a custom menu then your app needs to use the menus endpoints.

Comment: @ziico the pages endpoint is not how you show a menu, and has nothing to do with custom menus, that it listed the pages you expected is purely a coincidence

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.